# Python method wont recognize parameter

Tags: python, function, methods, parameters

So Im working on an extracurricular gui to learn python and to review topics I have learned in school such a rsa, fib and other math related topics.

I am trying to use a general purpose clearOptFrame(self, frame) that can be called while any frame is operating to reset back to the main Option frame (So to go from RSA frame to Main Menu, clearOptFrame(rsaFrame) would be called and the user would be returned to the main menu)

But for some reason my code isnt recognizing the parameter (frame) that I pass to it.
Here is my code:

```
#middle of calling function
global backButton
backButton = Button(optimizeFrame, text="Back", command = clearOptionFrame(optimizeFrame))

backButton.pack()

goButton2.pack()

#Clears the frame and inits main menu
def clearOptionFrame(self, frame):
    frame.pack_forget()
    initOptionFrame()
```

and when I run this code I get the error claiming that clearOptionFrame() takes no params:

```
  File "mathGUI.py", line 26, in optInit
    backButton = Button(optimizeFrame, text="Back", command = clearOptionFrame(optimizeFrame))
TypeError: clearOptionFrame() takes no arguments (1 given)
```

why is this???

Comment: You probably have another function with the same name outside of your class in your scope. You can't call a class-function that is not static without `self` reference, i.e. `self.clearOptionFrame()`

Comment: Ah yes, I did have a function with the same name, however now clearOptFrame(frame) is ran even if the backButton is not clicked..why is this?

Comment: Again, you're running the *other* function - not the one you think you're running...